# bash curl username credentials within script

Tags: bash, curl

I am passing username and password to the curl command to receive the output from the api call. Not sure whats wrong, but the curl command works from the command line, but when I use the same curl command within a bash script, it doesn't take the credentials properly. API call fails with an authorization error. Can someone throw some pointers here?

`curl --silent -u 'blah-blah:youareawesome$1234' https://example.com/api/check`

Here is the script

`USERNAME=$1
PASSWORD=$2
curl --silent -u "${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}" https://example.com/api/check`

`{"timestamp":1509422967185,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Bad credentials","path":"/api/check"}`

Comment: `USERNAME != USER` ? however, PASSWORD=PASSWORD ;-) If that solves your problem, please delete this Q as misspellings in code are off-topic. Good luck.

Comment: Also, `$USER` is a reserved variable name (automatically set to the current username). It's best to use lowercase (or mixed-case) variable names to avoid conflicts like this.

Comment: @shellter, I edit the question to avoid confusions. Thanks

Comment: @GordonDavisson, thats a good point, I changed the username to mixedcase and noticed the same error again. I have updated the question with the error stacktrace

Comment: With that fixed, it *should* work. Are you properly quoting the arguments to the script? Also, try adding `set -x` ti the script just before the `curl` command, so it'll print the equivalent of what it's actually running (note: what it prints isn't literally what's being executed, it's something *equivalent* to it, but sometimes with strange quoting or escaping of arguments).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UNAME=$1
PASSWORD=$2
curl --silent -u "${UNAME}:${PASSWORD}" https://example.com/api/check
```

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote
>   curl --silent -u 'blah-blah:youareawesome$1234' https://example.com/api/check

This might be a red herring on the quotes but your script won't accept strings after the `$` sign.

Might need to wrap your username & password in quotes as you give your script your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the answers !! For whatever reason, after i modified the script to have the username and password as separate variable and passing to the curl command worked

`CREDS="${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}"
CURL_CMD="curl --silent -u ${CREDS}"
${CURL_CMD} https://example.com/api/check`

Comment: I would *not* recommend doing this. Putting the command in a variable shouldn't solve anything, and will cause trouble if e.g. the password contains space or anything in `$IFS` (or maybe some shell wildcard characters or... See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)). If this appears to fix the problem, it's likely there's actually something else going on that you haven't understood yet and it may reappear later. Switch to lowercase variables, try `set -x`, and find out what's *really* happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,
example:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://119.235.1.63/test' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{ "CompanyId":"mafei", "Pword":"mafei123", "SmsMessage":"I am '${USER}'", "PhoneNumber": [ "712955386"] }'
```

in your code please use single quotes like below

```
curl --silent -u "'${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}'" https://example.com/api/check
```